# uninstalling system applications on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, uninstall

I am attempting to fully uninstall stock applications on my mac, such as dvdplayer. However, the system does not allow deletion of the application. Is there any way to uninstall these applications? I have tried numerous uninstalling programs to no avail.

Comment: Are you serioulsy strapped for space?  Mac OX X is highly integrated OS, so I don't know that it's even be a good idea.  However, I am curious to see if this possible since you pose the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use App cleaner and once installed, goto app cleaners 'preferences' and uncheck the 2 'protect already running applications' or whatever it says, checkboxes, then search for the apps you wanna delete. Then delete 'em.

Comment: I unchecked "Protect Default OSX Apps" in AppCleaner, but still get [this](https://imgur.com/a/suD7Q)

Answer (score 1):

Just run `sudo rm -r /Applications/DVD\ Player.app/` in Terminal. You can use `mdfind "dvd player"` or `mdfind $(osascript -e 'id of app "DVD Player"')` to find support files.

The applications probably get reinstalled when you upgrade OS X though. And there aren't that many practical reasons to delete them. There are more than 100 applications in /System/Library/CoreServices/ and other system directories.

Comment: I tried the sudo command you suggest and get this "override rw-r--r--  root/wheel restricted,compressed for /Applications/DVD Player.app//Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources?"